# get an integer from a webservice using jquery.ajax

Tags: asp.net, web-services, jquery

Every time I use a **success** function of jQuery.ajax I get the following result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">-105</int>
```

No matter what dataType I set (json, html, xml) - that's the returned data.
How can I escape the integer (-105 in this case)?

P.S. maybe I have to change somethig in my asp.net c# web method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public int CheckRegistrationFree(string phone)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me

```
$.ajax({
    success : function(xml){
        alert($(xml).find('int').text());
    }
})
```

Comment: that's the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined